# Exporting with ArcMap over 2000 dpi

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, export, jpg, geology

I am a geology student trying to export a map I produced in very high resolution so I can zoom in and across the ground with speed and still be able to see all the detail.

My base map is 5cm resolution satellite imagery and the map is about 12x7km in area (comes out to 67km^2 so as you can imagine things are pretty large).

I have exported at 2000dpi to JPEG and it works but is too fuzzy in the detail.

Trying to export at more than that, however seems to always fail (I managed to get a 3000dpi PDF but then Adobe Acrobat rolled over and played dead when I tried to zoom in)

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried to reduce the area I am exporting as much as possible to keep the resolution down but I think 3k dpi is necessary and it might even need to be more. File size is not an issue (I'm already at 200mb for my 2000dpi JPEG and 1.5Gb for my 3k dpi PDF)

My PC cannot run all of the files for the base map I need at once to make panning smooth which is why I am trying to export it to avoid waiting many seconds for things to load as it makes it hard to track geological beds.

Comment: JPEG is a *lossy* format. The fuzziness you're seeing is the image itself.

Comment: Try tiff, the file size will be significantly larger?